# Why this cookie-set code not work via smarty but does with 'direct' php

Tags: php, memcached, smarty, setcookie

The core of this question is to ascertain why the same code, when enclosed by {php} tags in a smarty template - doesn't work fully, compared to when the 'same code' is contained in  tags (in a non-smarty template). Specifically, the smarty code version (though partly functioning) isn't returning users to their original landing page.

More info: Am utilising a script which provides a smarty template framework for customisation. On other 'pure php' template sites I've been utilising the following code for the gateway page and all other pages respectively. Part of the functionality of the code is that after being first directed to the gateway page (if they don't have relevant cookie set), users (after getting a cookie) are then redirected back to the page they originally landed on.

[Because so similar, will just include the smarty version. Only difference are the opening and closing tags.]

Code on all pages except gateway page:

```
{php}
    session_start(); 
    function check_if_spider()
    {
        $spiders =     array('Googlebot','google','Yammybot','Openbot','Yahoo','Slurp','msnbot', 'ia_archiver','Lycos', 
            'Scooter','AltaVista','Teoma','Gigabot','Googlebot-Mobile','Baiduspider','R6_FeedFetcher','NetcraftSurveyAgent',
            'Sogou web spider','bingbot','facebookexternalhit','PrintfulBot','msnbot','Twitterbot','UnwindFetchor','urlresolver','Butterfly', 'TweetmemeBot', 'ia_archiver');

// Loop through each spider and check if it appears in
// the User Agent
foreach ($spiders as $spider)
{
    if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$spider) == true)
        return TRUE;
 }
 return FALSE;
}

if (check_if_spider() == false) {
           if (empty($_COOKIE["accepted"])) {
           $_SESSION["page_address"] = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
           header("Location: http://www.domain.name/gateway.shtml");
           exit; 
           }       
    }
{/php}
```

This is code on gateway page (actually, this is a non-smarty generated php page, so normal php tags used)

```
<?php

$inoneday = $_SESSION['inoneday'];
if (empty($inoneday)) $inoneday = '';

$baseaddress = $_SESSION['baseaddress'];
if (empty($baseaddress)) $baseaddress = '';

$page_address = $_SESSION['page_address'];
if (empty($page_address)) $page_address = '';

session_start();
//Expire 25 days in the future
//seconds * minutes * hours * days + current time
$inoneday = 60 * 60 * 24 * 25 + time(); 
setcookie('accepted', date("G:i - m/d/y"), $inoneday);
if ($_SESSION["page_address"] != NULL) {
$baseaddress = "http://www.domain.name";
header('Location: '.$baseaddress . $_SESSION['page_address']);
exit; }
else {
header("Location: http://www.domain.name/index.php");
exit; }
?>
```

When a user lands on one of the site pages, they are correctly redirected back to the gateway page - just that after the gateway page, they are always directed back to: http://www.domain.name/index.php and not their original landing position. Thus it seems that these lines in the smarty template are not working, or transferring info:

```
$_SESSION["page_address"] = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
```

and that

```
if ($_SESSION["page_address"]
```

is always equalling null.

Why is this and what can I do to fix it.

Comment: `session_start();` should be called before addressing to `$_SESSION`

Comment: Thanks for that Cheery, appreciated. It's not the fix (was hoping for a while!), but pleased to get that correct. Am now wondering if the issue is happening because all pages are cached using memcache system. Have found that whatever page $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] is placed on, that it always returns: index.php

Comment: Solution to this issue was to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to retrieve unique page address, rather than $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] (due to .htaccess rewrites in operation). Kudos to Bepe for this solution.